# Batch script git commit with dynamic comment

Tags: git, batch-file, command-line, git-commit

I am using a .bat file to commit a project to git and github. I would like it to take one optional argument that is the username of the person calling the file. That will be passed in using the command line. Don't worry about that part, it works fine. The part that is not working is the `git commit -m "%comment%"` line. The `ECHO %comment%` line prints out what I would expect it to print, but then it's not being passed to the git comment. The text `%comment%` is the comment being passed in instead of `Saved on Mon 10/11/2021-21:45:34.59 by makpo`. What am I doing wrong?

```
@ECHO OFF

SET comment=Saved on %date%-%time%

IF "%~1"=="" GOTO COMMIT
SET username=%1
SET comment=%comment% by %username%

:COMMIT
ECHO %comment%
git checkout development
git add .
git commit -m "%comment%"
git push origin
```

**GitHub**
[image]

> NOTE: I also posted this on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1681255/batch-script-git-commit-with-dynamic-comment), but I'm never really sure if that is the right place to ask these kinds of questions. Also, I feel like overflow has a lot more engagement.

Comment: You should generally not [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)…

Comment: @aschipfl - 
"Ideally link to the question on the other site and explain what you hope to learn from asking another community."
I did that. I linked to the other site and I explained why I posted it here also.

Comment: Why dont you use commit-msg hook ?

Comment: When a line of code is read by the parser, it expands the value of the variable before the line of code is executed.  What you are saying really isn't possible from a batch file with the code you are using.

Comment: @Dmitry - I don't know what that is. I've never used it before.

Comment: @Squashman - And yet, here we are. That is the code exactly as I have it and you can see the result.

Comment: Remove `@ECHO OFF` from the top of your batch file.  Open up a command prompt and run the batch file from there instead of executing it with your mouse. [Edit] your question with all the verbose output.

Comment: @ToMakPo please have a look at : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

you might find it extremely useful. search for commit-msg in your particular case